# System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005) error while start and stop window services

Tags: c#, .net, service, msmq

Actually, I have window service that read MSMQ queuw at an interval. My MSMQ queue is working without an issue but problem is when I stop or start windows service then it's throws an error. The complete error is given below:

```
**ERROR 65 DAL.MsmqImportListener - A MSMQ error occured
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005)
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.AsynchronousRequest.End()
at DAL.MsmqImportListener.PeekCompleted(Object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)**



private static void PeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msmq = sender as MessageQueue;
        var messageProcessor = e.AsyncResult.AsyncState as MessageProcessorMethod;
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                msmq.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);
                var message = msmq.ReceiveById(
                    e.Message.Id,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MsmqReceiveTimeout"])),
                    MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
                messageProcessor(message);
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }

        catch (MessageQueueException mqe)
        {
            // Check if timeout...no action if timeout, else log error
            if (mqe.MessageQueueErrorCode != MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout)
            {
                Logger.Error("A MSMQ error occured", mqe);
                EmailDispatcher.SendInformationEmail("A MSMQ error occured" + Environment.NewLine + mqe);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Error(
                string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "An unexpected error was encountered, message with id {0} was put in error queue: {1}",
                    e.Message.Id,
                    success),
                ex);

        }
        finally
        {
            msmq.BeginPeek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MsmqPeekTimeout"])), messageProcessor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511865/messagequeueexception-0x80004005-access-to-message-queuing-system-is-denied

Comment: Yes, I tried this solutions but not worked! my queue name is in small letter and i can't change queue name.

Comment: Do you have access to the code? Would you be able to log the full stack trace to a log file?

Comment: I have update the code but not have full stack trace

Comment: Can you add 'Log' on each step, it is possible that the exception is not caught by your code. it could be failed cast the sender, or e;  temporarily comment the 'if (mqe.MessageQueueErrorCode != MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout)'

Comment: i have updated error description! you can check it going inside  catch (MessageQueueException mqe) and do  Logger.Error("A MSMQ error occured", mqe);

Comment: Ah..., so the exception is thrown inside the 'using' statement, is it possible to add some log on each step to see values of 'e.AsyncResult, Id, MsmqReceiveTimeout' etc. Also add some log inside the messageProcessor method.

Comment: i can't do more log in code because it's happening only on production not at AT/DEV/Stage etc.