# Client Not read remote MSMQ queue, but can send to remote queue

Tags: c#, msmq

I have Windows Service developed in C#

I have Windows Server 2012 with 2 private queues: queueRequests and queueResponses.

My queues are **not transactional**.

I have Client that execute Console Application with credentials MyDomain\UserDeploy .

Windows Service in Server is executed with credentials MyDomain\UserAgent.

MyDomain\UserAgent and MyDomain\UserDeploy user has Full control about queues: queueRequests and queueResponses.

Server and Client are in the same MyDomain.

Console Application Client to send message and read message from/to private queue in Server.

Windows Service in Server to send message and read message from/toprivate queue.

Execution Steps:

1. Console Application Client send Message A to private Queue
   queuerequests in Server
2. Windows Service read Message A from private queue queuerequests
3. Windows Service sendMessage B to private queue queueresponses
4. Console Application Client read Message B from private queue
   queueresponses.

It was working all steps.

Now, I don't know the reason, the step 4 fails. **Client Not reads message from remote queue.**

I don't understand why: Client can send message to queue, but not reads from queue.

I get a **MessageQueueException** but exception.Message  is empty.

Any suggestions for get good troubleshooting ?

Fragment code:

```
    const string ForSend = @"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\private$\DeploymentCommands";
    const string ForRead = @"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\private$\DeploymentResponses";

 private DeploymentResponse WaitForResponse()
        {
            try
            {
                Message rsp = colaStatus.ReceiveByCorrelationId(correlationId, new TimeSpan(0, timeOut, 0));
                DeploymentResponse ret = rsp.Body as DeploymentResponse;

                Console.WriteLine("Respuesta WaitForResponse:" + ret.DeploymentId + " - " + ret.Status);
                Trace.WriteLine("Respuesta WaitForResponse:" + ret.DeploymentId + " - " + ret.Status);
                return ret;
            }
            catch (MessageQueueException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error WaitForResponse in remote server " + remoteServer + ". " + ex.Message);
                Trace.WriteLine("Error WaitForResponse in remote server " + remoteServer + ". " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

More about **MessageQueueException** .

I get

**Message:  null**
**MessageQueueErrorCode -2147023169**
**ErrorCode -2147467259**

but not found that code in MessageQueueErrorCode Enumeration.

-2147023169 value. In Hex: **800706BF**

-2147467259 value. In Hex: **80004005**

Not much info about those codes. Only I get:

> 0x80004005 -2147467259 E_Fail
>   0x800706BF -2147023169 PRC_S_Call_Failed_DNE

[Windows Update Codes](http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm)

Full trace exception:

> Message:  - MessageQueueErrorCode -2147023169 - ErrorCode-2147467259
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
>
> at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveBy(String id, TimeSpan timeout,
>   Boolean remove, Boolean compareId, Boolean throwTimeout,
>   MessageQueueTransaction transaction, MessageQueueTransactionType
>   transactionType)
>
> at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(String
>   correlationId, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at DeploymentAgent.Client.DeploymentInvoker.WaitForResponse()

Comment: Are you using transactions? Can you add few lines of code with reading/writing part? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Try catching exception and check [MessageQueueErrorCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeueerrorcode.aspx). Could you also show the Path you are using to access remote private queue?

Answer (score 0):

Things you might try:

1. Changing queue permissions - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731627/win-service-getting-permission-denied-to-message-queuing), try setting permission to "Everyone" (for the test only).
2. Try setting `AllowNonauthenticatedRPC` in registry - [details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/12/msmq-4-0-what-s-new-in-computer-management.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

May you should consider to use **`public`** instead of `private` queues. Read the following articles of the advantages of public queues:

- [Destination Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706878(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Public and private queues](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346(v=ws.10).aspx)